Can't acess my server anymore
I'm really new at these things, like, Linux, Servers and etc...
Anyways, I had a server in my old laptop with Ubuntu Server, I used tailscale to have a easy way to acess the server and organize files. Recently I changed my network, this laptop was connected to wifi, so now, it doens't have acess to it now. I try to ping google.com and it just appears "Temporary failure in name resolution" what can I do to connect to the wifi again? I just want my old dog pictures which is saved in the server.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Can you ping Cloudflare DNS at 1.1.1.1?

Maybe you set up a static address (which is usual on a server)? Since your network has changed, it may try to get an IP address that your router can't handle. Do ip a. This will give you the current IP address that it is trying to obtain. Compare it to other devices on the network (e.g. your phone).

@karel when I exec that it appears "Network Unreacheable"

@Jos hey, so, I executed this command, it appears a lot of info, not of them seems to be my ip. I din't found it, at least. Before my internet used dynamic IP, I bought the static IP a week ago. I don't remember how I used to start the tailscale and etc, do you know how can I do this? I just need to connect the wi-fi, I remember I used to get my ip again to connect to the server, but I don't remember how to do it anymore...
